# Display error messages from j_exception on error page on unsuccessful login (JAAS - LoginException Handling)

Tags: jsf, tomcat, jaas

Display custom error messages on unsucessful login using jaas's j_exception

I have configured tomcat to work with jaas to authenticate my users. I have made use of form based authentication and hence on unsuccessful login i navigate to an error page. Instead of an error page with static message, I wish to display appropriate messages like "Invalid username/password" or "User locked"(i lock the user after 5 unsuccessful attempts) etc from j_exception

How can i achieve this?

I tried googling around the issue and found the following link
http://www.jroller.com/heonkoo/entry/manipulating_login_exception
But this seems like an old post.

I have been struggling with this from a few days. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

JAAS does not provide a standard way to propagate information to the web layer.

You can use a ThreadLocal to store the exception and read it in your error page.

Comment: An example is required.